# How to get image with quality in percentage in node js public/uploads/image

Tags: node.js, image, express, image-processing

i need save only one original image in my folder but retrieve different different quality vise.

For E.g. 
This image has 5% quality: https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/880/1056/jrp8r680/sari/m/k/g/free-1468-kashvi-sarees-original-imafdfszdcpvcwrp.jpeg?q=5

[image]

This image has 100% quality:
https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/880/1056/jrp8r680/sari/m/k/g/free-1468-kashvi-sarees-original-imafdfszdcpvcwrp.jpeg?q=100

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to check the file size and then just pick the largest?

Comment: @BraveButter it's have Only one image not multiple.

Comment: So you wish to convert an image of, say 100% to 5%? Is this correct? or Do you wish to determine the quality  % from the file?

Comment: Quality is not fixed it's dynamic pass in Image URL ?q=70 or any other value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to convert quality levels, I'd suggest trying [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp). This allows us to convert Jpeg image quality easily.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const Jimp = require('jimp');

function getImage(imageFile, qualityPercent) {
    return Jimp.read(imageFile)
    .then(image => {
        // Convert to new quality level %
        return image.quality(qualityPercent).getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);
    });
}

app.get('/images/:imageFileName', async (req, res) => {
    let imageFileName = req.params.imageFileName;

    // Get the quality requested in percent, e.g. /images/original_image.jpeg?quality=15
    let qualityPercent = Number(req.query.quality) || 100;
    let imageBuffer = await getImage(imageFileName, qualityPercent);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
        'Content-Length': imageBuffer.length
    });

    console.log(`Serving ${imageFileName} at ${qualityPercent}% quality...`);
    res.end(imageBuffer);
});

app.listen(port);
```

Run this server and you can request an image with the url (for example):

```
http://localhost:3000/images/original_image.jpeg?quality=25
```

Comment: it's code create new image but i need to fetch same image with different different dynamic quality

Comment: Then the code above should do pretty much what you need, we can read the image from a url or a filename, convert it and save to another file, or serve it.

Comment: i not need to save new file just fetch that image file with dynamic quality

Comment: That should be easy enough, we can convert the image to a buffer and serve that!

Comment: I've updated the answer with the latest changes, you can set the quality level in the url, e.g. http://localhost:3000/images/original_image.jpeg?quality=25

Comment: Okay after i check conform it.

Comment: Great, glad to hear!